# Calculating area difference between two polygon shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, area

I have two polygon shapefiles which contain about 30 features. These features have different boundaries in both shapefiles so the areas are different too.

I want to calculate that difference in the area for each feature using QGIS. Shall I use the intersection tool for that?

Comment: you should use 'difference' instead of intersect.

Comment: @eurojam But how I can know difference between each feature if I use difference tool. That will just delete intersecting areas and keed the rest.

Comment: I would compute the areas, join the two datasets on your common key field, and then subtract that the two area columns from each other.

Comment: Do you have access to geopandas? This is very easy in geopandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the Field Calculator to calculate the area in each layer (we'll call them Layer 1 and Layer 2). Store these value as attributes, eg "L1_area" for the area of Layer 1, and "L2_area" for the area of Layer 2.
2. Join the "L2_area" attribute to Layer 1.

   - If your layers have an attribute with shared values, you can achieve this with a [table join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#defining-1-n-relations-relation-manager).
   - If your layer doesn't have a shared attribute, AND corresponding features overlap each other (but not other features), you can do a spatial join instead (`join attributes by location` tool).
3. Calculate the difference between "L1_area" and "L2_area"

   ```
   "L1_area" - "L2_area"
   ```